Why does applying Ladder operators change the eigenfunction?
When applying a ladder operator to a spherical harmonic function, it spits out the function with a lower or higher magnetic quantum number.
My question is how does this abide by the classical eigenfunction/eigenvalue relation? Surely an operator acting on an eigenfunction should spit out the exact same function multiplied by the corresponding eigenvalue?
My initial guess it that the ladder operator is made up of multiple operators which is what causes this but I’m not entirely sure.

Why do you think the spherical harmonic is an eigenfunction of the ladder operator?

"Surely an operator acting on an eigenfunction should spit out the exact same function multiplied by the corresponding eigenvalue?" Yes, but are you applying it to an eigenfunction?

Thank you! Just to clear up some misunderstanding- operators only spit out eigenvalues when applied to eigenfunctions specific to that operator? And the spherical harmonics are eigenfunctions of the angular momentum squared operator but not the ladder operators? In that case do the ladder operators have any eigenfunctions and what do they represent? And how does applying an operator to not it’s eigenfunction yield anything useful?

You are correct in your first statement. The ladder operators do not have spherical harmonics as their eigenfunctions. They are just meant to turn one spherical harmonic into another; that is their entire purpose for being constructed.

Exercise: find the eigenfunctions of the ladder operator. (There must be functions for which it actuaily does give you a multiple of the function itself. Every matrix over $\mathbb C$ has at least one eigenvector...)

@JosBergervoet after many many attempts at trying to solve for them I figured out that the only eigenfunctions are harmonics where m = +l for L+ and m = -l for L-, as this gives you an eigenvalue of 0 which technically makes them count as eigenfunctions. As much of a pain as it was, thanks for the exercise it was worth doing :)


Surely an operator acting on an eigenfunction should spit out the exact same function multiplied by the corresponding eigenvalue?

This is only true for the operator for which the function is an eigenfunction. Being an eigenfunction is not a property only of a function, but rather of a function relative to a certain operator.
Namely, for the spherical harmonics, the relations
$$L² Y_{lm} = \hbar^2 l(l+1) Y_{lm}$$
and
$$L_z Y_{lm} = \hbar m Y_{lm}$$
hold, but $L_x Y_{lm}$ is not proportional to $Y_{lm}$. $Y_{lm}$ is an eigenfunction of $L^2$ and of $L_z$, but not of all operators.
